# Foreach loop, and array building

Tags: php, string

I have an admin area where they can delete multiple users at a time. This is part of the code that handles the deletion. Basically it goes through the user ids and deletes each one that was marked checked.

```
if ($_POST['doDelete'] == 'Delete') {
    if (!empty($_POST['u'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['u'] as $uid) {
            $id = escape($uid);
            $delete = Nemesis::query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '{$id}' AND id <> '{$_SESSION[user_id]}'");
            if (!$delete) {
                $msg->add('e', QUERY_ERROR);
                redirect('users.php');
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
    /* we need a way to iterate over users deleted */
    $msg = new Messages();
    $msg->add('s', QUERY_DELETE_SUCCESS);
    redirect('users.php');
    exit();
}

function get_user_name_from_id($user_id)
{
    if ($_SESSION['user_level'] == ADMIN_LEVEL) {
        $viewUserMod = 1;
    } else {
        $config = Nemesis::select("usr_view_cm", "config");
        $row_config = $config->fetch_assoc();
        $viewUserMod = $row_config['usr_view_cm'];
    }
    if (is_numeric($user_id) && $viewUserMod == 1) {
        $sql = Nemesis::select("full_name", "users", "id = {$user_id}");
        if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
            $user_name = $sql->fetch_assoc();
            return $user_name['full_name'];
        } else {
            // user name cannot be matched with db, either error, or most likely user was deleted
            return 'User ' . $user_id;
        }
    } else {
        return $user_id;
    }
}
```

Where it says `QUERY_DELETE_SUCCESS` I would like to output something like *"Deleted Bob, Jack, Tim"* .etc I have a function that uses the users id and gets their names. The issue is that once the iteration is complete. Obviously those users *no longer exist* in the database and I cannot get their names. **Is there a way of running this function during the loop, and building a string or array. That can be outputted in place of the message?**

Comment: Which means you have to call your getname function and use it to build an array of deleted user names __before__ executing each delete statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to do this:

```
if ($_POST['doDelete'] == 'Delete') {
    $deleted = array();
    if (!empty($_POST['u'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['u'] as $uid) {
            $id = escape($uid);
            $username = get_user_name_from_id($uid);
            $delete = Nemesis::query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '{$id}' AND id <> '{$_SESSION[user_id]}'");
            if (!$delete) {
                $msg->add('e', QUERY_ERROR);
                redirect('users.php');
                exit();
            }
            $deleted[] = $username // push name to array after deletion is successful
        }
    }
    /* The $deleted array now holds the names of the deleted users.
     * Do with it what you want.
     */
    $names = implode(",", $deleted)
    $msg = new Messages();
    $msg->add('s', QUERY_DELETE_SUCCESS . " Deleted: $names");
    redirect('users.php');
    exit();
}
```

There are several improvements that can be made here, including efficiency (combining many small single queries into a few larger ones) and error handling (don't redirect on the first error - instead redirect after all processing is complete to a page with a list of successes and errors), but this is the basic idea.

Here is a quick change that will do all of the operations, even if one of them errors:

```
if ($_POST['doDelete'] == 'Delete') {
    $deleted = array();
    $errored = array();
    if (!empty($_POST['u'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['u'] as $uid) {
            $id = escape($uid);
            $username = get_user_name_from_id($uid);
            $delete = Nemesis::query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '{$id}' AND id <> '{$_SESSION[user_id]}'");
            if (!$delete) {
                $errored[] = $username;
            } else {
                $deleted[] = $username // push name to array after deletion is successful
            }
        }
    }
    /* The $deleted array now holds the names of the deleted users.
     * The $errored array now holds the names of users who were not deleted due to errors.
     * Do with them what you want.
     */
    $msg = new Messages();
    $names_deleted = implode(",", $deleted)
    $msg->add('s', QUERY_DELETE_SUCCESS . " Deleted: $names_deleted");
    if (count($errored) > 0) {
        $names_errored = implode(",", $errored)
        $msg->add('e', QUERY_ERROR . " Did not delete: $names_errored");
    }
    redirect('users.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: if for example we have 3 deletions. the first one works, the second one doesnt, and the third also works. how can you tell which one succeeded and which one failed?

Comment: i think i got it. so basically if it fails do one array, and if it passes than do another array. then in the end check if they are both empty. if they both arnt then display the users that were and werent deleted?

Comment: @Alex Yes, that's close to how I would do it.  I have updated my example.

Comment: yea thats pretty much the same as how i wrote it. except for i used `if(!empty($fail)) ...` any difference between doing a count vs empty for an array? because i read they achieve the same things.

Comment: @Alex Yes, `count($array) > 0` and `! empty($array)` will do the same thing: check whether the array has any elements.  It's largely a matter of personal preference which one you use.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the names to an array as you are looping over the uids with something like this:

```
$names = array();
if (!empty($_POST['u'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['u'] as $uid) {
        $names[] = get_user_name_from_id($uid);
        $id = escape($uid);
        $delete = Nemesis::query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '{$id}' AND id <> '{$_SESSION[user_id]}'");
        if (!$delete) {
            $msg->add('e', QUERY_ERROR);
            redirect('users.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you want to output the confirmation message, you could turn that array into a comma separated string with something like this:

```
$names = implode(', ',$names);
$message = "Deleted $names";
```